# SQL count doesn't work with null

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    customers.customerNumber, customers.customerName,
    customers.state, customers.city,
    COUNT(orders.customerNumber) AS OrdSum
FROM 
    customers 
INNER JOIN 
    orders ON customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
WHERE 
    (customers.state <> 'NY') AND (customers.country = 'USA')
GROUP BY 
    customers.customerName
ORDER BY customers.customerNumber;
```

This is my sql code. The table with COUNT doesn't show the row with 0 value..

Comment: You can use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: still doesn't work bro

Comment: A left join **will** show the zero counts if you keep  the `COUNT(orders.customerNumber)`

Comment: You have to provide more in information in your question.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT c.customerNumber, c.customerName, c.state, c.city,
       COUNT(o.customerNumber) AS OrdSum
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN 
     orders o
     ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
WHERE c.state <> 'NY' AND c.country = 'USA'
GROUP BY c.customerNumber, c.customerName, c.state, c.city
ORDER BY c.customerNumber;
```

This should show *all* customers in NY along with the number of orders they have, even if they have no orders.  I am curious though:  how could someone be in a table called `customers` if they have no orders?